# IdentityServer4 oidc w/ angular2 Guard Always False

Tags: javascript, angular

I have identity successfully authenticating a user, it passes the user back to the main site which runs

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/oidc-client/1.2.2/oidc-client.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="waiting">Waiting...</h1>
<div id="error"></div>
<script>
    new Oidc.UserManager().signinRedirectCallback().then(function (user) {
        if (user == null) {
            document.getElementById("waiting").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("error").innerText = "No sign-in request pending.";
        }
        else {
            window.location = "/";
        }
    })
    .catch(function (er) {
        document.getElementById("waiting").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("error").innerText = er.message;
    });
</script>
```

But when it its the home page "/" it keeps going back to unauthenticated because of

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal';

import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { UnauthorizedComponent } from './components/unauthorized/unauthorized.component';

import { AuthService } from './services/shared/auth.service';
import { AuthGuardService } from './services/shared/auth-guard.service';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent, 
        UnauthorizedComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        UniversalModule, // Must be first import. This automatically imports          BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule too.
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {
                path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'home',
                component: HomeComponent,
                canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
            },
            {
                path: 'unauthorized',
                component: UnauthorizedComponent
            }
        ])
    ],
    providers: [AuthService, AuthGuardService]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Where AuthGuard is

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
    }
    canActivate() {
        if (this.authService.loggedIn)
        {
            alert("this"); //<--- never happens 
            return true;
        }
      alert(this.authService.loggedIn); //<---  always false, happens before everything else?
        this.router.navigate(['unauthorized']);

    }
}
```

And where AuthService is

```
    import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { UserManager, Log, MetadataService, User } from 'oidc-client';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    mgr: UserManager = new UserManager(settings);
    userLoadededEvent: EventEmitter<User> = new EventEmitter<User>();
    currentUser: User;
    loggedIn: boolean = false;

    authHeaders: Headers;


    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.mgr.getUser()
            .then((user) => {
                if (user) {
                    this.loggedIn = true;
                    alert("loggedin"); //<--- Happens all the time
                    this.currentUser = user;
                    this.userLoadededEvent.emit(user);
                }
                else {
                    this.loggedIn = false;
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                this.loggedIn = false;
            });
        this.mgr.events.addUserUnloaded((e) => {
            this.loggedIn = false;
        });
    }
    clearState() {
        this.mgr.clearStaleState().then(function () {
            console.log("clearStateState success");
        }).catch(function (e) {
            console.log("clearStateState error", e.message);
        });
    }

    getUser() {
        this.mgr.getUser().then((user) => {
            console.log("got user", user);
            this.userLoadededEvent.emit(user);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    removeUser() {
        this.mgr.removeUser().then(() => {
            this.userLoadededEvent.emit(null);
            console.log("user removed");
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    startSigninMainWindow() {
        this.mgr.signinRedirect({ data: 'some data' }).then(function () {
            console.log("signinRedirect done");
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    endSigninMainWindow() {
        this.mgr.signinRedirectCallback().then(function (user) {
            console.log("signed in", user);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

    startSignoutMainWindow() {
        this.mgr.signoutRedirect().then(function (resp) {
            console.log("signed out", resp);
            setTimeout(5000, () => {
                console.log("testing to see if fired...");

            })
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    };

    endSignoutMainWindow() {
        this.mgr.signoutRedirectCallback().then(function (resp) {
            console.log("signed out", resp);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    };
    /**
     * Example of how you can make auth request using angulars http methods.
     * @param options if options are not supplied the default content type is application/json
     */
    AuthGet(url: string, options?: RequestOptions): Observable<Response> {

        if (options) {
            options = this._setRequestOptions(options);
        }
        else {
            options = this._setRequestOptions();
        }
        return this.http.get(url, options);
    }
    /**
     * @param options if options are not supplied the default content type is application/json
     */
    AuthPut(url: string, data: any, options?: RequestOptions): Observable<Response> {

        let body = JSON.stringify(data);

        if (options) {
            options = this._setRequestOptions(options);
        }
        else {
            options = this._setRequestOptions();
        }
        return this.http.put(url, body, options);
    }
    /**
     * @param options if options are not supplied the default content type is application/json
     */
    AuthDelete(url: string, options?: RequestOptions): Observable<Response> {

        if (options) {
            options = this._setRequestOptions(options);
        }
        else {
            options = this._setRequestOptions();
        }
        return this.http.delete(url, options);
    }
    /**
     * @param options if options are not supplied the default content type is application/json
     */
    AuthPost(url: string, data: any, options?: RequestOptions): Observable<Response> {

        let body = JSON.stringify(data);

        if (options) {
            options = this._setRequestOptions(options);
        }
        else {
            options = this._setRequestOptions();
        }
        return this.http.post(url, body, options);
    }


    private _setAuthHeaders(user: any) {
        this.authHeaders = new Headers();
        this.authHeaders.append('Authorization', user.token_type + " " + user.access_token);
        this.authHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }
    private _setRequestOptions(options?: RequestOptions) {

        if (options) {
            options.headers.append(this.authHeaders.keys[0], this.authHeaders.values[0]);
        }
        else {
            options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.authHeaders, body: "" });
        }

        return options;
    }

}

const settings: any = {
    authority: 'http://localhost:5000/',
    client_id: 'js',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:38881/auth',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:38881/',
    response_type: 'id_token token',
    scope: 'openid profile api',

    silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:38881',
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    //silentRequestTimeout:10000,

    filterProtocolClaims: true,
    loadUserInfo: true
};
```

**The problem is that any attempt to go to home or / results in going to unauthorized even though   alert("loggedin"); happens**

It seems like
alert(this.authService.loggedIn); //<---  always false, happens before everything else, which is the issue why is canactive going even though the result from authservice hasn't returned

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm trying to implement the same sample code that comes with this library (oidc-client) and I'm facing exactly this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. The problem is that the Promise in the AuthService constructor is resolved after AuthGuardService checks whether the user is logged in. To fix this I created a new function in the AuthService:

```
isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
  return Observable.fromPromise(this.mgr.getUser()).map<User, boolean>((user) => {
    if (user) return true;
    else return false;
  });
}
```

Then, rewrite the canActivate function of the AuthGuardService to use the isLoggedIn() function instead of relying on the AuthService constructor:

```
canActivate() {
    let self = this;
    let isloggedIn = this.authService.isLoggedIn();
    isloggedIn.subscribe((loggedin) => {
        if(!loggedin){
            self.router.navigate(['unauthorized']);
        }
    });
    return isloggedIn;
}
```

This canActivate implementation returns an Observable instead of a boolean, to let it wait for the Promise in the AuthService to complete. There is also a subscription so we can decide whether to redirect to unauthorized or not.

Also see this issue: https://github.com/jmurphzyo/Angular2OidcClient/issues/21